# Why is the phrase "applied for" used in the past tense here?

Tags: grammar, tense, conditional-constructions, subjunctives

**The paragraph I have a question with:**

> If I were in a position where I were a principal hiring teachers, I would definitely hire Leah. She would be an asset to any teaching staff, and judging her by her work ethic and ability to get along with others, I would hire her for any job that she **applied for**.

It is from a recommendation letter on LinkedIn.
(https://www.linkedin.com/in/leah-thomas-24393568)

---

**Question:**

(1) Why is the phrase "**applied for**" used in the past tense here?

(2) Does the past tense use of the phrase "**applied for**" here have anything to do with the second conditional use in the paragraph?

---

**Why I think the original phrase is a bit weird:**

I think the phrase should be "applies for" in the present tense because it can mean a general idea of her applying for jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not indication of the past tense but of the subjunctive.

You could say, in a different context:

"I will hire her for any job that she applies for."

... but starting with the "would", which expresses the sentence as a hypothetical (she hasn't applied, she may not apply, we don't know, but if she *were* to apply, *then* I *would* hire her) means that "applies" has to be changed to "applied", because, er, that's how it works.

Because the sentence starts "If I were ..." expresses the fact that "I" cannot actually *be* in a position to hire her, because I am not the decision-maker in the company she applied for. The sentence is already a hypothetical one.

In short, the original sentence quoted is completely correct.

Comment: It is a correct sentence, but from a style perspective, I still have a problem with ending a formal sentence with a preposition.  It's fine for emails, text messages, and notes to friends but this appears to be a letter of recommendation. I realise this is my personal view and nothing to do with the original query.

Comment: @BruceMurray I believe that to be another of those rules of faux style invented by the ludicrously class-conscious Victorians, along with not beginning a sentence with a conjunction and not splitting the infinitive. Churchill famously debunked it with "This is [something] up with which I will not put."